# Can I accompany my mother-in-law at port of entry in US

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I have a Green card and my mother-in-law would be on a visitor's visa .Can I accompany her in the Visitors line at the port of entry in US . She does not speak or understand English .And we are travelling together

Comment: You ought to be able to take your mother in law with you to the LPR line.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. You are traveling together and related by marriage, and you serving as her interpreter will be helpful.

[Who is eligible to file a joint or family declaration on a CBP Form 6059B?](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/441/~/travelers-eligible-to-file-a-joint-or-family-declaration-on-a-cbp-form-6059b)

> In accordance with 19 CFR 148.34(b) member of a family residing in one
>   household includes all persons who meet the following three
>   conditions: 1. **Are related by blood, marriage**, or adoption;

Comment: The page you link to has three criteria, all of which must be met, and it looks like the other two are not.  However, when I (a US citizen) visited the US in 2003 or so with my then-girlfriend who lived in an entirely different country from me (she was using the visa waiver program), the officer tore up her customs declaration form and added her to mine.  He also confirmed that it was appropriate for us to use the US citizens' line together.